# stop postfix local relay / external mail server

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

i have decided to have a separate mail server for my app. When i use php to send email, postfix sends successfully to other domains(gmail.com etc), but uses local relay for the addresses hosted on my mail server. The MX record works fine. All i need is to get the local addresses out. I dont know where to start. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `relayhost` configuration option.  In your /etc/postfix/main.cf file, enter a line containing `relayhost = mail.foo.com`.  This should make all outgoing mail go through mail.foo.com.


--Christopher Karel

Answer (score 0):

```
postconf -e "local_transport = error:No local mail delivery"
```

Answer (score 0):

postconf -e "local_transport = smtp:[external.relay]"

Comment: What does that do, why should it work?