# postfix delivery of mail to the same domain with external relay

Tags: postfix, g-suite, ubuntu-20.04

I was looking at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/174788/stop-postfix-local-relay-external-mail-server) to solve my issue but I see that I already set it.

The point is: I am running postfix to deliver mail using Gsuite. If I deliver mail to any other domain it works fine. If I send mail to an address `@mydomain` it will try to dispatch it internally. I want to force posftix to send it using Gsuite SMTP anyway.

The log shows:

```
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/pickup[277348]: 84DFB1E3E9: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/cleanup[277442]: 84DFB1E3E9: message-id=<20201006154442.84DFB1E3E9@mydomain.com>
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2082]: 84DFB1E3E9: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/local[277444]: 84DFB1E3E9: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "admin")
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/cleanup[277442]: 8AD961E3EA: message-id=<20201006154442.8AD961E3EA@mydomain.com>
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/bounce[277445]: 84DFB1E3E9: sender non-delivery notification: 8AD961E3EA
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2082]: 8AD961E3EA: from=<>, size=2331, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2082]: 84DFB1E3E9: removed
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/local[277444]: 8AD961E3EA: to=<www-data@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Oct  6 17:44:42 mydomain postfix/qmgr[2082]: 8AD961E3EA: removed
```

Note that admin is not an user defined on the server, so the mail is bounced.
My hostname is `mydomain.com`

My postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_wrappermode =  yes



relayhost= [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:465
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = thesmartred.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
# Enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# Disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# Location of sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
# Location of CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this doesn't work, it will cause a bunch of other errors in the log

Answer (score 1):

Actually I solved using the transport directive.
I added to my main.cf the following:

```
transport_maps =  hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Then I created the transport file using

```
*  smtp:[smtp-relay.gmail.com]:465
```

that will deliver all the email using gmail smtp (internal and external).

and then I run

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Finally I restarted postfix and everything is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You put your domain name in `mydestination`. This tells Postfix that it is meant to handle mail being sent to the domain, so it tries to deliver such mail locally.

For a mail server that is meant to relay everything, the naked domain name should not be in `mydestination` or in the file `/etc/mailname`. (A subdomain is fine.)

Further, the system hostname should never be set to the naked domain name, as this will also confuse Postfix.